# How to manage database connection pool in spring jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am using spring-boot in my web application and use spring-jpa to read/write from/to my database. It works very well but I want to understand how to manage the database connections. Below is my properties configuration for database:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=500
```

I have set the maximum connections to 500. When a user makes a request on my spring application, a database connection will be opened for him. After finishing the request, will spring jpa close this connection? If not, when will it close the unused connections?

I have read through the spring jpa reference document from http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/. But it doesn't mention anything about the connections.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using DB connection pooling, a call to `sqlconnection.close()` will not necessarily close the heavyweight connection to the database, instead most often will just release the connection as re-usable in the pool. That's why it is advisable to invoke the `close()` on connection as soon as possible when leveraging a client side connection pool.

In your configuration, the pool will contain a maximum number of 500 connections ( it would be also good to configure `maxIdle`, `minIdle`, and `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` to tune the number of ready-to-use connections and how often to release them when not used).

Some more doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: the problem is that I am using jpa repository name convention to read/write database. How can I get sqlconnection instance?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 14):

You have already found that you can configure this from `application.properties`
You can find all the possible properties [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix).

Notice that from Spring Boot 1.4 there are datasource properties for every datasource vendor that spring integrates with, out of the box. There is `spring.datasource.dbcp.*`,`spring.datasource.tomcat.*` and so on. See [1.4 docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix)

If that's not enought, and you need something very specific, you can declare the datasource bean yourself. Here is the example with Tomcat datasource:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
     PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
          p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");
          p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          p.setUsername("root");
          p.setPassword("password");
          p.setJmxEnabled(true);
          p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
          p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
          p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
          p.setTestOnReturn(false);
          p.setValidationInterval(30000);
          p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
          p.setMaxActive(100);
          p.setInitialSize(10);
          p.setMaxWait(10000);
          p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
          p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
          p.setMinIdle(10);
          p.setLogAbandoned(true);
          p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
          p.setJdbcInterceptors(
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
          DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
          datasource.setPoolProperties(p);
          return datasource ;
}
```

Comment: where can I find all these properties explanation? I only found declaration but no detail explain.

Comment: You have to dig in the API https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html

Comment: @Evgeni Hi. I have been trying to find a connection pooling mechansim for my mongoDB access. There are no straight forward implementations that I know f=of and I cannot find a sample to do that. Currently I used Mongorepositories but I am afraid that in prod that is not a right way to handle? Could you let me know of any ?

Comment: @Joey587 I'm not an Mongo expert and ideally you should ask a separate question about this. Nevertheless take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698222/connection-pooling-in-spring-boot-and-mongo-db

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov Thank you. I did look at it before but it did not say anything about the datasource. I will post a seperate question though. Thank you