# Connection pooling in Spring Boot and mongo db

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, connection-pooling

I am going through spring boot application and mongoDb connection POC. 
I have added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also I have gone through mongoB properties with properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Can you please how do we define connection pooling mechanism here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this out of the box with application properties. You need to make use of MongoClientOptions to configure various aspects of connection pool.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.Builder.html) for various options available.

Here is a simple example.

```
@Bean(name="mongoTempl")
public MongoTemplate mongoTempl() throws Exception {
     return new MongoTemplate(createMongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port))
                              ,dbName);
}


Mongo createMongoClient(ServerAddress serverAddress) {
final MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder()
        .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(...)
        .connectionsPerHost(...)
        .connectTimeout(...)
        .maxWaitTime(...)
        .socketKeepAlive(...)
        .socketTimeout(...)
        .heartbeatConnectTimeout(...)
        .minHeartbeatFrequency(...)
        .build();

        return new MongoClient(serverAddress, options);
}
```

Comment: Cant find  `MongoClientOptions` in latest version is there any alternative ?

Comment: With a quick look, I can see that `MongoClientSettings` is what you should use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer like in this spring [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/e737388f5c81dedf3c48d25766dbf7037e524dbf/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-data-mongodb/src/main/java/smoketest/data/mongo/SampleMongoApplication.java)

```
@Bean
public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer customizer() {
    return (builder) -> builder.applyToConnectionPoolSettings(
            (connectionPool) -> {
                connectionPool.maxSize(10);
                connectionPool.minSize(2);
                connectionPool.maxConnectionIdleTime(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                connectionPool.maxWaitTime(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                connectionPool.maxConnectionLifeTime(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                connectionPool.addConnectionPoolListener();
            });
}
```