# Connection pool in MongoDB with jongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, connection-pooling, jongo, connection-pool

I would like to use connection pool for MongoDB. I have used MongoDB with Jongo and Spring MVC framework.

Here is my spring xml code for MongoDB configuration, which is working fine.

```
<!-- Mongo Configuration -->
<mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="${mongodb.host}" port="${mongodb.port}">
</mongo:mongo>

<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="${mongodb.database}" username="${mongodb.username}" password="${mongodb.password}" />
```

I need to configure a connection pool. Can anyone guide, How to implement MongoDB connection pool with existing code?

Comment: You can transfer this XML setting into the Java file and where you can easily set the connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the following helps
https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot

Also, a similar question seems to be asked
[Connection pooling in Spring Boot and mongo db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698222/connection-pooling-in-spring-boot-and-mongo-db)