# mongo repository always new connection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin

We have use the below code to connect to documentdb as below

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query
import abc.apidigitalwellnesscs.models.DBDigitalWellnessUser


interface UserRepository: MongoRepository<DBDigitalWellnessUser, String> {

   fun save(data: DBDigitalWellnessUser): DBDigitalWellnessUser
   @Query(value = "{ 'mdmid' : ?0 }")
   fun findByMdmid(mdmid: String): DBDigitalWellnessUser
}
```

and below is the simple config for mongodb uri

```
spring:
 data:
  mongodb:
   uri: ${DATABASE_URI}
```

I have found that this code does not limit connection base on default 100 connecton pool and found the socket timeout error, it spike up to 1600 - 1800 connection as capture screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGbXC.png)

Do any one know what is the problem or what I have done wrong

Comment: you can configure your connection pool as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/50698459/175554